# Can I improve this query for use in large tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I improve this query for use in large tables....?

I use a table ('DataValues') to store a collection of values ('Value') for collections ('Visit_id') ie it records certain values for each visit.

I use a table ('MatchItems') to store dynamic match sets 'MatchSet' of values ('Value'), sets can contain any number of values.  The table also has a IsNeg field to indicate if the match should require a value to be not present in the visit collection.

This allows me to dynamically match visits that conform to certain criteria such as
Must contain values A, B and C and NOT D OR C and B AND NOT A.

ie (Value = A and Value = B and Value = C and Value /= D)
or (Value = C and Value = B and Value /= A)

I have a query that delivers a reasonable solution [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb6202/3):

```
CREATE TABLE DataValues (
 id NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT DataValues_pk PRIMARY KEY,
 Visit_id Number(5) ,
 Value varchar(5) 
);
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (1, 1, 'M');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (2, 1, 'I');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (3, 1, 'C');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (4, 1, 'K');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (5, 1, 'E');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (6, 1, 'Y');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (7, 2, 'M');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (8, 2, 'O');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (9, 2, 'U');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (10, 2, 'S');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (11, 2, 'E');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (12, 3, 'C');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (13, 3, 'A');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (14, 3, 'T');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (15, 4, 'S');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (16, 4, 'A');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (17, 4, 'T');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (18, 5, 'M');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (19, 5, 'A');
INSERT INTO DataValues VALUES (20, 5, 'T');

CREATE TABLE MatchItems (
 id NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT MatchItems_pk PRIMARY KEY,
 MatchSet Number(5),
 Value VARCHAR(5),
 IsNeg NUMBER(1) NOT NULL CHECK (IsNeg in (0,1))
);

INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (1, 1, 'M', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (2, 1, 'I', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (3, 1, 'C', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (4, 1, 'K', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (5, 1, 'E', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (6, 1, 'Y', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (7, 2, 'C', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (8, 2, 'A', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (9, 3, 'A', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (10, 3, 'T', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (11, 4, 'S', 1);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (12, 4, 'A', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (13, 4, 'K', 1);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (14, 5, 'A', 0);
INSERT INTO MatchItems VALUES (15, 5, 'T', 0);

SELECT
MatchItems.MatchSet,
DataValues.Visit_id,
GpMatchItems.Count TgtCount,
Count(MatchItems.Id),
sum(MatchItems.IsNeg)

FROM DataValues
LEFT JOIN MatchItems ON MatchItems.Value = DataValues.Value 
--AND MatchItems.MatchSet = 4
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
       MatchItems.MatchSet,
       count(*) Count
      FROM MatchItems
      WHERE 
      MatchItems.IsNeg = 0
      GROUP BY
      MatchItems.MatchSet) GpMatchItems ON GpMatchItems.MatchSet = MatchItems.MatchSet

HAVING
Count(MatchItems.Id) = GpMatchItems.Count
AND sum(MatchItems.IsNeg) = 0

GROUP BY 
MatchItems.MatchSet,
DataValues.Visit_id,
GpMatchItems.Count
```

How can I improve the performance of this query where the DataValues table contains 100m records, and MatchItems may include a collection of 50 sets each of 2 - 20 values?

Comment: The first thing to consider is how many rows does your query **read**. Your filtering condition `IsNeg = 0` seems to be selecting 60% or more of the rows; in a 100-million rows table, the query is **reading** 60 million rows. It's OK to do that for a batch query that can take hours to run, but not for an interactive one. What's your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this version using Analytic functions and see if it performs any better. This query removes the subquery `GpMatchItems` that you are joining with.

```sql
  SELECT DISTINCT matchset,
                  visit_id,
                  tgtcount,
                  match_visit_count,
                  isneg_sum
    FROM (SELECT MatchItems.MatchSet,
                 DataValues.Visit_id,
                 COUNT (DISTINCT CASE MatchItems.IsNeg WHEN 0 THEN MatchItems.id ELSE NULL END)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY MatchItems.MatchSet)
                     AS tgtcount,
                 COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchItems.MatchSet, DataValues.Visit_id)
                     AS match_visit_count,
                 SUM (MatchItems.IsNeg) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchItems.MatchSet, DataValues.Visit_id)
                     AS isneg_sum
            FROM DataValues LEFT JOIN MatchItems ON MatchItems.VALUE = DataValues.VALUE)
   WHERE tgtcount = match_visit_count AND isneg_sum = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks EJ This did the trick, it significantly improved the performance.

Comment: Hi EJ - there is a problem with this solution, the tgtCount counts all the MatchItems in a MatchSet that match, it should count all the MatchItems in a MatchSet and then we use tgtCount to check we have ALL the required Matches.  

If I edit the 'Y' in MatchItem.Id to 'Z' it still returns Visit_ID as valid even though MICKEY /= MICKEZ.

Comment: In your sample query, you are only counting MatchItems where `isNeg = 0` and that is what my solution is doing. If you do not care about the `isNeg` value, then just remove the case statement and use `MatchItems.id`

Comment: In the sample isNeg = 0 ensures none of the Negative matches are included and the Sum of the Matches found must be the same as the sum of the Matches required in the MatchSet, that was why I included the Join to GpMatchItems to count all the MatchItems required in each MatchSet.

Comment: The tgtCounts is only counting MatchItems records that have a match somewhere in the DataValues table as the LEFT JOIN is ON MatchItems.VALUE = DataValues.VALUE.  The join will be exclude MatchItems that have no match but we need to know how many (with IsNeg=0) MatchItems there are in the MatchSet to ensure they are ALL satisfied.  Can we use Count Over Partition without using another Join?

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted EJ's suggestion to include a LEFT JOIN to collect the tgtCount to identify the total number of good matches required in each MatchSet:

```
SELECT DISTINCT matchset,
              visit_id,
              tgtcount,
              match_visit_count,
              isneg_sum
              GpMatchItems.count tgtCount 
FROM 
             COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchItems.MatchSet, DataValues.Visit_id)
                 AS match_visit_count,
             SUM (MatchItems.IsNeg) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchItems.MatchSet, DataValues.Visit_id)
                 AS isneg_sum
        FROM DataValues 
        LEFT JOIN MatchItems ON MatchItems.VALUE = DataValues.VALUE)
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                     MatchItems.MatchSet,
                     count(*) Count
                 FROM MatchItems
                 WHERE MatchItems.IsNeg = 0
                 GROUP BY
                     MatchItems.MatchSet) GpMatchItems 
                 ON GpMatchItems.MatchSet = MatchItems.MatchSet
         )
WHERE 
tgtcount = match_visit_count 
AND isneg_sum = 0;
```